# $n = 2^p - 1$ Prove that if n is prime then p must also be prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

My first thought was to try a contradiction; So given n is prime assume p is not prime i.e $p = p_{1}^{\alpha1} .... p_{r}^{\alpha r}$. But i didnt know where to go from there.

Comment: Try to use that $a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+...+b^{k-1})$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $p = a\cdot b $ where $a \neq 1, b \neq 1$ then $n = 2^{ab} - 1 = (2^a)^b - 1 = (2^a-1)(2^{a(b-1)} + ...+ 1)$ is clearly composite.

Comment: I love this. Is there another proof or approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $p$ is not a prime, and let $k$ be $p$'s smallest prime divisor.

We have $2^k-1|2^p-1$ and $2^k-1 > 1$, so $2^p-1$ cannot be a prime as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If $1<x\le y$ then $2^x-1$ divides $2^{xy}-1$. Moreover $1<2^x-1<2^{xy-1}$, which is enough to conclude.